# variable in SQL query - PHP MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, variables

I have 2 variable holding dates. I am getting a syntax error in the SQL statement when I use the variables.

```
$from_date = '2013-02-13';
$to_date = '2013-02-20';
$query="SELECT * FROM mytable where datex >= ".$fromdate." AND datex <= ".$todate.";
```

Help me identify and correct this syntax error?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

You need to quote your variables:

```
$query="SELECT * FROM mytable where datex >= '".$fromdate."' AND datex <= '".$todate." . "'";
```

But it would be better to use a prepared statement with bound variables. Then your query could look like (PDO):

```
$query="SELECT * FROM mytable where datex >= :fromdate AND datex <= :todate";
```

Answer (score 0):

im doing something similar would this be the correct way to do it ?

```
  <?php
  include 'connect.php';

  $id1 = $_POST['PatientID']; //Text box the user searches in
  $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM PatientRecords WHERE PatientID= '".$id1."'");
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
```